# How could any one access the private files on server using windows app

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a windows app in c# .NET which requires access to the file on the sever.

Ex:--user A has his credentials as A and pswd. He has server space where he has the file i need.

i have the credentials. I can access it using our website. But, i need to access it using a windows app

Imagine i need a file stored on the mail a/c of a user.

Please help.

Comment: Is "the server" part of your domain or a remote machine?  If it's part of the domain, does this user have an account with the domain?

Comment: yes it is part of our domain and the user has the accoun with the doamin

Comment: You need to tell us the protocol over which you want to access the file (FTP/HTTP(S)/FILE) and the authentication type you want to support (plain text, Windows integrated, or something else). if you don't know or don't care about these two, the best approach would be to secure the files using the NTFS ACLs and expose them over a shred folder and get them from the client using the File class and the UNC name.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on how the file is stored on the server in question. If it's a file in their mail account, you could login to the mail server and search through their mail for it.

If it were a file on the harddrive, you could login via FTP and download it. The devil is in the details though, so you really need to provide more information about what you are actually trying to do.

- [FTP library in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftplib.aspx)
- Email using [POP3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx) and [IMAP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx)

Comment: we have bunch of users on our server each with a credential. We have various portals too. I am trying to access the file on a user space using a windows app

Comment: What type of credentials? Windows login information? Some custom credentials for a website? FTP credentials? Mail server credentials? SSH credentials?